# Infopath forms with code on SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath-2013

We are migrating infopath forms from SP2010 to SP2016. Our infopath forms have C# code also.
My query is do we need to install infopath 2013 on the server where SharePoint 2016 is installed to run infopath forms? As it is a server so don't have permission to install anything. So please confirm is it mandatory to install infopath 2013 on the servers?

Comment: I posted the answer in detail here- [https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/291235/how-to-upgrade-infopath-2010-forms-to-infopath-2013-to-deploy-on-sharepoint-2016/291236#291236](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/291235/how-to-upgrade-infopath-2010-forms-to-infopath-2013-to-deploy-on-sharepoint-2016/291236#291236)

Answer (score 0):

InfoPath 2013 client is not a must to run InfoPath forms on SharePoint 2016, but you will need to use the client to publish the forms if they are migrated from previous version or from another farm.

As long as you have done customizing and publishing the forms, you can use it on any server in this farm, no InfoPath 2013 required.

Remember to configure InfoPath Forms Services via *Central Administration* > *General Application Settings* if this is the first time you use InfoPath in the new farm.

Reference: [Configure InfoPath Forms Services In SharePoint 2013 Central Administration.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/configure-infopath-forms-services-in-sharepoint-2013-central-administration/)

Comment: Hi Chelsea,

Thanks for your reply. I am able to publish the form, but while uploading it on SP farm I am getting error "There is an error in the InternalStartup method of form code". I commented the code inside InternalStartup method , still getting same error. So actual problem I am facing is while uploading form template on SP Farm. Please help.

Comment: @Preeti Here is an article on same error you can refer to: https://samirfarid.wordpress.com/2011/08/09/internalstartup-method-error-when-publishing-infopath-form-with-custom-code/

Comment: I have already gone through this article. This article is about when we get this error while publishing the form. But in my case, I was able to publish the form successfully and was getting that error on SP farm while uploading form template in central admin.

Comment: Thanks for your support @Chelsea. My problem is resolved now. Approach was to upgrade 2010 forms to 2013 and then publish and upload on SP farm. It is working well now.

Comment: @Preeti Thanks for sharing. You can post this solution as a new Answer and accept it so that we can help others with similar problem in this forum.

Comment: I posted the answer in detail here- https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/291235/how-to-upgrade-infopath-2010-forms-to-infopath-2013-to-deploy-on-sharepoint-2016/291236#291236