# How to Upgrade InfoPath 2010 forms to InfoPath 2013 to deploy on SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath, designer

I want to deploy InfoPath 2010 forms to SharePoint 2016. These are Admin Approved browser based forms. Please help with the steps to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** I struggled a lot and finally got the solution.

**Prerequisite required-**

InfoPath Designer 2013, you can get this with Office 2013 Proplus subscription.

Visual Studio 2012.

Visual Studio Tools for Application (2012)

**Steps:**

First open the existing 2010 Form in Infopath Designer 2013.

Got to File -> Save As ->

Select **InfoPath Web Browser Form Template(*.xsn)**   -> Save

Go to File -> Form Options
OR
Developer -> Language -> Programming -> Select **InfoPath** in Target Version dropdown -> OK.

That's it, your InfoPath 2010 Form is upgraded to InfoPath 2013. Now you can change the Data Connection by selecting new sites.

Now you can Publish and deploy this on SharePoint 2016 Server from Central Admin as usually.

Comment: Glad to hear that. You could mark the solution as 'Accepted answer' which will help others  directly find the answer in the future.